# ¿Cómo paso información de una función a otra?

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando cómo obtener la información de la función *uno* para usarla en la función *dos*

```js
function uno() {

var a = "Texto aquí";
var b = "Enlace aquí";

}


function dos() {

var txt = /* Traer el texto de la variable a */

if (/**/) {

var url = /* Traer el link de la variable b */

}

}
```

Comment: Para devolver un valor desde una función, existe la sentencia `return`. También puedes usar el alcance de variables, de tal forma que las mismas estén disponibles globalmente para ambas funciones. Todo dependerá de lo que realmente necesites.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí una manera de hacerlo retornando un array asociativo e imprimiéndolos.

```js
dos();//llama la función dos() para ejecutarla

function uno() {

var a = "Texto aquí";
var b = "Enlace aquí";
return {"a":a, "b":b}; //retorna array de objetos
}


function dos() {

var mi_funcion = uno();//Obtiene resultado del return

var txt = mi_funcion["a"];//obtiene el texto por medio del key
console.log(txt);//imprime lo que contiene

var enlace = mi_funcion["b"];//obtiene el enlace por medio del key
console.log(enlace);//imprime lo que contiene

}
```